# Why the max value is not correct from dataframe in pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe named as orders, loaded from csv file, while the *days_since_prior_order* column has some blank values.

```
orders = spark.read.csv("/Users/yanan.chen/Downloads/instacart/orders.csv",header=True)
orders.createOrReplaceTempView("orders")
spark.sql("select * from orders limit 30").show()

+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
|order_id|user_id|eval_set|order_number|order_dow|order_hour_of_day|days_since_prior_order|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2539329|      1|   prior|           1|        2|               08|                      |
| 2398795|      1|   prior|           2|        3|               07|                  15.0|
|  473747|      1|   prior|           3|        3|               12|                  21.0|
| 2254736|      1|   prior|           4|        4|               07|                  29.0|
|  431534|      1|   prior|           5|        4|               15|                  28.0|
| 3367565|      1|   prior|           6|        2|               07|                  19.0|
|  550135|      1|   prior|           7|        1|               09|                  20.0|
| 3108588|      1|   prior|           8|        1|               14|                  14.0|
| 2295261|      1|   prior|           9|        1|               16|                   0.0|
| 2550362|      1|   prior|          10|        4|               08|                  30.0|
| 1187899|      1|   train|          11|        4|               08|                  14.0|
| 2168274|      2|   prior|           1|        2|               11|                      |
| 1501582|      2|   prior|           2|        5|               10|                  10.0|
| 1901567|      2|   prior|           3|        1|               10|                   3.0|
|  738281|      2|   prior|           4|        2|               10|                   8.0|
| 1673511|      2|   prior|           5|        3|               11|                   8.0|
| 1199898|      2|   prior|           6|        2|               09|                  13.0|
| 3194192|      2|   prior|           7|        2|               12|                  14.0|
|  788338|      2|   prior|           8|        1|               15|                  27.0|
| 1718559|      2|   prior|           9|        2|               09|                   8.0|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

As you can see, there are some blanks in `days_since_prior_order`, which as actually ''. `spark.sql("select * from orders where days_since_prior_order <> '' ").show()`

```
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
|order_id|user_id|eval_set|order_number|order_dow|order_hour_of_day|days_since_prior_order|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
| 2398795|      1|   prior|           2|        3|               07|                  15.0|
|  473747|      1|   prior|           3|        3|               12|                  21.0|
| 2254736|      1|   prior|           4|        4|               07|                  29.0|
|  431534|      1|   prior|           5|        4|               15|                  28.0|
| 3367565|      1|   prior|           6|        2|               07|                  19.0|
|  550135|      1|   prior|           7|        1|               09|                  20.0|
| 3108588|      1|   prior|           8|        1|               14|                  14.0|
| 2295261|      1|   prior|           9|        1|               16|                   0.0|
| 2550362|      1|   prior|          10|        4|               08|                  30.0|
| 1187899|      1|   train|          11|        4|               08|                  14.0|
| 1501582|      2|   prior|           2|        5|               10|                  10.0|
| 1901567|      2|   prior|           3|        1|               10|                   3.0|
|  738281|      2|   prior|           4|        2|               10|                   8.0|
| 1673511|      2|   prior|           5|        3|               11|                   8.0|
| 1199898|      2|   prior|           6|        2|               09|                  13.0|
| 3194192|      2|   prior|           7|        2|               12|                  14.0|
|  788338|      2|   prior|           8|        1|               15|                  27.0|
| 1718559|      2|   prior|           9|        2|               09|                   8.0|
| 1447487|      2|   prior|          10|        1|               11|                   6.0|
| 1402090|      2|   prior|          11|        1|               10|                  30.0|
+--------+-------+--------+------------+---------+-----------------+----------------------+
```

But, what confused me is that when I excute `spark.sql("select min(days_since_prior_order),  max(days_since_prior_order) from orders where days_since_prior_order <> '' ").show()` The max value in result is not correct.

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|min(days_since_prior_order)|max(days_since_prior_order)|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|                        0.0|                        9.0|
+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

What's wrong with my codes ?

Comment: All the columns' type are string.

Comment: '9.0' > '30.0' in string type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the column from String to a numeric type.
Do something like:

```
 from pyspark.sql.functions import col
 orders = orders.withColumn('days_since_prior_order',
        col('days_since_prior_order').cast('double'))
```

Then you will get the correct result.

Another way is to use udf (user defined functions, but why complicate when we make simple.)

Comment: Do you know how to show the orders df in the way of order by days_since_prior_order which has already been converted to integer? I just show() it buy 10 is in front of 2 while 10 is after 1.

Comment: Not sure I understand well your question, but if you want the values in order you could visualize the results by doing  df.groupBy('days_since_prior_order').count().show()